# Is it Game time or game-time?

Tags: hyphenation, compounds

I'm trying to verify the correctness the following sentence:

> Game time is Sunday.

Is it correct or should it be "game-time"?

Comment: If you feel free to use slang, which is the only attribution I can find for the single-lexeme usage in dictionaries, surely the correctness of hyphenation shouldn't be a worry?

Answer (score 2):

In this case, where *game time* is the subject of the sentence, don't use a hyphen. When using it as a [compound modifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_modifier), you would usually want to use a hyphen to minimize confusion: *the game-time temperature will be 60 degrees*.